# HAML: tr[@user] translates to class and ID, but how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

As we know, HAML translates `tr[@user]` do `<tr class="user" id="user_123">...`. But how does it achieve this? Through some internal magic? Or using some functionality of the `@user` object?

What I want to achieve is the following. I have a `Contact` model with a `Company` and a `Person` subclass. Now when using `tr[@company]`, I'd like HAML to do the following:

```
<tr class="contact company" id="company_123">
```

...instead of only:

```
<tr class="company" id="company_123">
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: `tr.contact[@company]`?

Comment: Sure this works, but I'd like HAML to make this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `haml_object_ref` method in your model to override what Haml uses as the value of the `class` attribute.

If you only use direct subclasses of `Contact` something simple like this should work in your `Contact` model:

```
def haml_object_ref
  "#{self.class.superclass.to_s.underscore} #{self.class.to_s.underscore}"
end
```

(this uses the ActiveSupport `underscore` method.)

If you want to use `Contact` instances directly, or subclasses of `Person` or `Company`, you could do something like this:

```
def haml_object_ref
  classes = []
  klass = self.class
  while klass <= Contact
    classes << klass
    klass = klass.superclass
  end
  classes.map{|c| c.to_s.underscore}.join(' ')
end
```

This would produce `class="contact"` for an instance of `Contact`, `class="contact person'` for an instance of `Person` and `class="contact person employee"` for a (hypothetical) `Employee` subclass of `Person`.

Comment: When I don't want to override haml_object_ref but just get the generated ID from an object, what can I do? @user.haml_object_ref is not available on a model by default.